# Can you use the tag <span> within .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, innerhtml

I'm starting with programming and I was making a "Tic-Tac-Toe" game in HTML using Javascript. I was just thinking how could I make the 2nd value change it's color and I came up with the span tag, but the thing is that I don't actually know if I can use it there or not.

```
function dibujar(){
    for( i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if(mapa[i] ==0) document.getElementById("c"+i).style="background-color:white";
        if(mapa[i] ==1) document.getElementById("c"+i).innerHTML = "X";
        if(mapa[i] ==2) document.getElementById("c"+i).innerHTML = "O";
```

Could you help me with this please?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you to use `element.style.color` instead

Comment: What's wrong with `html` instead?

Comment: The problem is that when I click on one of the table's cells, it comes up with a "X" or an "O" (that's why the innerHTML), and I want it to change the color of the O (that's why I thought of the span tag).

Comment: Just use 2 classes, 1 for each player, each with a different colour. When the square is occupied, set the class of the element to the corresponding class, You can use `document.getElementById(idHere).classList.add(classnameHere);`